# Debugging an JNI memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

I wrote a small Java JNI program that does nothing but eternally creating an array of tuples `(arr[i], arr[i+1])` from an array `arr`. Meanwhile, I use `ps aux` to record the RSS memory usage every minute and I noticed a steady increase of about 11 KB each minute on average. The JNI code is as follows:

```
/*
 * Class:     com_example_Main
 * Method:    shift
 * Signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_example_Main_shift(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobjectArray s) {
    jsize n = env->GetArrayLength(s);

    auto ret = (jobjectArray) env->NewObjectArray(n, env->GetObjectClass(s), env->NewStringUTF(""));
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        auto js = (jstring) env->GetObjectArrayElement(s, i);
        auto next_js = (jstring) env->GetObjectArrayElement(s, (i + 1) % n);
        auto tuple = (jobjectArray) env->NewObjectArray(2, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), env->NewStringUTF(""));
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(tuple, 0, js);
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(tuple, 1, next_js);
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret, i, tuple);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

As far as I can see, there is no data that needed to be cleaned up here. So, I cannot really explain why the memory is changing over time at all.

In the Java main method, I create a long array with strings and then run above `shift` over and over:

```
public class Main {
    static {
        System.load("/path/to/a.so");
    }

    private static native String[][] shift(String[] s);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++) {
                sb.append(j);
            }
            input.add(sb.toString());
        }
        String[] arr = input.toArray(new String[0]);

        for (int it = 0; true; it++) {
            String[][] next = shift(arr);
            arr = Arrays.stream(next)
                    .map(a -> a[0])
                    .toArray(String[]::new);
        }
    }
}
```

I also wrote another version of this application where I replace the C++ code by a `return s` and change the response type of `shift` to `String[]` accordingly and that application indeed doesn't increase in memory at all after the first few minutes. That suggests that a memory leak is hidden somewhere in the C++ code.

`valgrind` isn't very helpful in this situation because it shows thousands of errors from the JVM, but none from my code.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the Java GC is simply not kicking in yet because there is enough free memory to keep allocating new tuples over and over again? Try running under `-verbose:gc` and/or limiting the memory size.

Comment: Not yet. Thanks for the hint, @Botje. So, I set the memory size of the JVM to just the right size to do one round.

Comment: I'm using [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io) now to debug it and it shows a zig-zag pattern for the actually allocated heap size. I think above method of checking memory requirement isn't very appropriate for Java programs. Let's see how it develops over time.

Comment: Yes, a zig-zag pattern is normal for a process that garbage collects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Botje correctly pointed out that you are technically not creating a memory leak, but calling any `New*` in a loop of arbitrary length is a red flag anyway. First, GC can't clean up after you until you return from JNI call back to JVM. So beware the size of Java `arr`, or split to multiple JNI calls on smaller chunks. Second, JNI has a limit on how many local references you can create in one native call. Simplified, how many times you can call `New*` without paired `DeleteLocalRef` or more modern `Push/PopLocalFrame`. The fact that a [default preallocation is 16 and limit 65535](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#ensurelocalcapacity) should give you a hint, that JNI designers were quite sensitive about this feature.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. My production code actually restricts the input size and the output size depends on the input size, so I think, this shouldn't be an issue in my production code. However, for the minimum working example here, I condensed everything to the bare minimum required to illustrate my question.

Comment: You're welcome.  Regardless of the production code restriction, controlling your local references lifecycle explicitly is a good practice. If nothing else, you are giving a hint to JVM GC, that you don't need those objects anymore. GC will clean up anyway eventually even without the hint, but it never hurts to help the JVM do its work faster and earlier.